# AdMob ad requires two clicks to activate when in a ListView?

Tags: android, admob

I put admob ads in my app. They appear as a footer view in a ListView. Strangely, the ad doesn't respond to the first click. I need to click it a second time for it to respond. Thereafter, it responds normally to all subsequent clicks.

I don't have a click listener assigned to the view that holds it. I don't have an OnItemClickListener assigned to the listview either. This is what the view looks like that I inject the admob view into (and this inflated view is added as the ListView footer).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:padding="5dp" >

  <!-- I add the Ad to this inner layout at runtime. -->
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/body"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:padding="5dp">
  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

...
View parent = inflateContainerFromXml(R.layout.foo);
parent.addView(makeAdMobView());
ListView lv = ...;
lv.addFooterView(parent);
```

I realize the nested layout above looks slightly weird but it's because of a visual style I'm trying to achieve.

Any idea what could be causing this? I think the admob view creation code should be ok, because I use it elsewhere in the app in a plain linearlayout and click handling behaves normally there.

Thanks

Comment: That's odd.  Are you sure the ad isn't a "2-click" ad where the first click just makes the open icon bigger?  If not, could you provide your AdMob code?  Optionally, you could also check out [this ListView example](http://code.google.com/p/google-mobile-dev/source/browse/adcatalog/src/com/google/ad/catalog/layouts/ListViewExample.java?repo=ad-catalog-android) which doesn't have the two-click problem.

Comment: I am heaving the same problem as @user291701 described. The odd thing is that the ad does show a tiny scrollbar, which could mean that the first click is indeed used to scale the ad a bit (although no scaling is visible). The answer provided by benway did solve the issue however!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem; solved by adding

`android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`

in the root layout of the listview item

Comment: had the same problem as the OP and this fixed it for me. I've added in the footer's root element's layout

Comment: I'm seeing this problem with Google Play Services 6.5.87 and Android versions 4.3 and earlier. There is also a narrow blue bar across the bottom of the ad when the user presses it, instead of the blue highlight that typically covers the entire ad. The following code fixes the problem, mAdView being a newly created instance of PublisherAdView: `mAdView.setDescendantFocusability(FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);`